# CSS Grid: let last autoplaced child fill up remaining columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I've defined a grid for an unknown number of autoplaced children:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(28rem, 1fr));
```

I need the last child to be autoplaced (meaning it starts at the column after the previous child or on a new row in the first column if the previous child is in the last column). The CSS line above takes care of that. Now how do I let the last child fill up the remaining space (until the last column), no matter on what column it starts?

I tried giving the child `grid-column-end: -1;`, but this simply places it in the final column.

Is it possible to make the last child to fill up remaining space without manually adding breakpoints or JavaScript?

Comment: Could  you elaborate what you want? The code provided places children in different rows within the same column, so saying that you want the last child to be in the row after the previous child in the same column is a non-issue. That's what this code already does. Did you get row and column swapped around? Could we get a functional code snippet?

Comment: Sorry Laif, I indeed mixed up 'row' and 'column' in my question. Fixed that.

The HTML shouldn't be interesting: a grid container with an unknown number of children in a flexible width container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a pure CSS solution, But here's a JS Way of achieving it.

```js
// Select Grid Container
let ctr = document.querySelector('[ctr]');
// Find how many Columns there is
let colCount = getComputedStyle(ctr).getPropertyValue('grid-template-columns').split(' ').length;
// Find how many elements there is
let elCount =  ctr.children.length;
// Find which column the last element is in
let lastElementColStart = elCount % colCount;
// Set it's start column to be the column it is
ctr.children[elCount - 1].style.gridColumnStart = lastElementColStart;
// Set it's end column to be the last one
ctr.children[elCount - 1].style.gridColumnEnd = colCount + 1;
```

```css
[ctr] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

[ctr]>div {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[ctr]>div:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div ctr>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You'll have to rerun the code on screen resize (i'll leave that to you)